Estimate the order of a function from the information of sublevel set
Let $u: \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$ be a convex function with $u \geq 0, u(0)=0$, denote the sublevel set as $S_h^0=\{ x\in \mathbb{R}^n :u(x)<h\}$. Now we have the following information about the sublevel sets:
$\qquad \qquad(1)$ There exist two universal constants $r_1,r_2>0$, so that $B_{r_1}(0) \subset S_1^0 \subset B_{r_2}(0)$
$\qquad \qquad(2)$There exists a constant $\theta \in (0,1)$ so that for any small $h>0$, one has $S_{h/2}^0 \subset \theta S_h^0$
$\qquad \qquad(3)$There exists a small constant $\sigma>0$ so that for any small $h>0$, one has $S_h^0 \subset S_{(1-\sigma)h/2}^0$
Show that there exist positive constants $\alpha,\beta,C$ so that $C^{-1}|x|^{1+\beta} \leq u(x) \leq C|x|^{1+\alpha} \quad$ near the origin.
Currently I have no idea about how to connect the sublevel set conditions with the order of $u$, I think the point is to use conditions $(2)(3)$ to control sublevel sets from two sides and do some iterations to push to the sublevel set $S_1^0$ to use condition $(1)$. But I don't know how to do this in detail. Also I don't see where the convex condition is needed. Any help is appreciated.
